# Facebook SDK 4.0 ShareDialog

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-share

I want to share an image from my Android app using facebook SDK 4.0. I got it to work with ShareDialog, but when the user doesn't have FB app installed, according to developers.facebook, SDK should use Web Share dialog instead:

> In past versions of the SDK for Android, your app had to check for a native, installed Facebook app before it could open the Share Dialog. If the person didn't have the app installed, you had to provide your own code to call a fallback dialog.
>
> Now the SDK automatically checks for the native Facebook app. If it
>   isn't installed the Web Share dialog launches:

But nothing happens when I delete FB app and try to share.
Here is my code:

```
            ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);

            BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            bmOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, bmOptions);

            SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(image).build();

            SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder().addPhoto(photo).build();

            shareDialog.show(content, ShareDialog.Mode.AUTOMATIC);
```

***EDIT***

Is there a way to share a photo on facebook without facebook app installed?

Comment: did you get any error ? check your logcat once you execute this code

Comment: I don't get anything. No errors.

Comment: hi, do we need any special permission to use this? with the new facebook sdk 4.0 ? @filipst

Comment: If you are using Facebook SDK 4.0 and you share via ShareDialog, you don't need any special permission. ShareDialog uses android facebook app to share content on your wall. But if you want to be able to share even if user doesn't have android facebook app installed, you need new publish_actions permission. @Rat-a-tat-a-tat Ratatouille

Comment: @filipst - thank you, just to confirm, this means that if i convert a file image to a bitmap and use the facebook app to share, i will not require any special permission correct? I actually tried doing this, but then i got an error while i was trying to login using login with read ..

Comment: No, you don't require any special permissions. What error did you get?  
You can add this to check if ShareDialog can be shown:
if (shareDialog.canShow(MainActivity.class)){...}
else{//tell user that he doesn't have fb app}

Comment: @filipst, so with the code in your question, you are able to share a photo to Facebook (if user has the FB app)? I tried your code, can't get it to work. :/ I click a share button, but nothing happens.

Comment: @Noni A. Try the code below in the answer.

Comment: @filipst, thanks I tried, but no share dialog appears when I click.

Comment: did you found any solution to share the photo without facebook app installed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution:

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePathForShare, bmOptions);

    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(image).build();

    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder().addPhoto(photo).build();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.facebook_uploading), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    ShareApi.share(content, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.facebookSuccessful), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel()
        {
            Log.v("FACEBOOK_TEST", "share api cancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e)
        {
            Log.v("FACEBOOK_TEST", "share api error " + e);
        }
    });
```

Comment: but you would need publish permissions from the user to use the ShareApi

Comment: Yes, I know. There is no way to share without facebook application and not ask for publish permissions.

Comment: Hi @filipst, I this with this solution, the sharedialog will not presented. Is that right?

Comment: did you found any solution to share the photo without facebook app installed ?

Answer (score 1):

Please read SDK documents carefully.
You cant share photo with sharedialog without Facebook App installed.

Refference : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

> Photos
>
> People can share photos from your app to Facebook with the Share Dialog or with a custom interface.
>
> The photos must be less than 12MB in size
>
> People need the native Facebook for Android app installed, version 7.0 or higher

Comment: So there is no other way to share a photo? What if user doesn't have FB app installed?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I have faced the same trouble and I can say that that there is some trouble in SharePhotoContent API of facebook. You can share the image using ShareLinkContent.

```
ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                    .setImageUrl("Your url")
                    .build();
shareDialog.show(linkContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use share dialog to share photos.

Try this

```
 Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                    SharePhoto.Builder photoBuilder = new SharePhoto.Builder();
                    photoBuilder.setBitmap(image);
                    photoBuilder.setCaption("HBD Caption");
                    final SharePhoto sharePhoto = photoBuilder.build();
                    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder().addPhoto(sharePhoto).build();
                    mShareDialog.show(content);
```

> To add caption, you'll need to add publish permissions from facebook.
>   If you wont do this, your image will get posted without a caption.

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/permissions/